# Reloading a web page does not work in web app

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications

I'm working on a simple note-taking web app. It features a navigation bar with a "New Note" button which, when clicked, displays a note creation form. It also has notes list content that displays a list of note titles.

When the web page is loaded, the `loadNotesList()` function is called. This function calls the Google Apps script to get the list of note titles. The list is then sorted from newest to oldest. Each title in the list is then used to create a button which, when clicked, loads the contents of the corresponding note.

There is something that is not working: when I close a note that I have consulted, I want it to display the home page as if it is the first time that it opens the app.

This is how I load the page at first (it works):

```
window.onload = function() {     
  loadNotesList();   
};
```

Here are the solutions I tried that didn't work:
Solution 1:

```
function closeNote() {
  // Vérifier si le formulaire de création de note est affiché
  var createNoteForm = document.getElementById('createNoteForm');
  if (createNoteForm) {
    // Masquer le formulaire de création de note
    createNoteForm.style.display = 'none';
  }

  // Afficher la page d'accueil
  loadNotesList();
}
```

Solution 2:

```
function closeNote() {
  // Effacer le contenu de la note
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '';

  // Recharger la page d'accueil
  window.location.reload();
}
```

Solution 3:

```
function closeNote() {
  // Effacer le contenu de la note
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '';

  // Masquer le formulaire de création de note
  var createNoteForm = document.getElementById('createNoteForm');
  createNoteForm.style.display = 'none';

  // Recharger la page d'accueil
  window.location.reload();
}
```

The page remains hopelessly blank... Why?

Comment: Its a bit unclear what you asking here.  Note: `window.location.reload();` will not remember anything clientside.  So `createNoteForm.style.display = 'none';` and the lines above will do absolutely nothing.

Comment: THANKS. I'm only trying to reload the web page as if opening the web app the first time. Or like when you press F5. There is no need to remember anything. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, `location.reload()` is like pressing `F5`.   There is likely something else causing you issues, if you open developer tools, what does the console say?.

Comment: You probably need to spend some time debugging you code with the browser and the debugger.

Comment: What does loadNotesList() look like?  Using templated HTML instead of windows.onload is much faster since it's all done server side but of course it can't be used for reloading.

Comment: The coseole gives no errors. When I open the note it says: "Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE". When I press the "Close" button, the web page turns white and the console displays nothing.

Comment: https://script.google.com/d/1qthQj4qNi2-a3ob0vp0Bwhku7vBQoS17VTOsZJWe9nxrN99p9CBTJqPV/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try `window.top.location.reload();`

Comment: Thanks TheMaster. It doesn't work better unfortunately... Is there another, completely different method to return to the home page and the list of notes?

Comment: Should be possible to do anything with JavaScript, even if reloading fails.